# Describing Consumer Group Null Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So let me try and describe this.. We are using Kafka version 1.1.1 and have a Kafka Streams application. There are 6 instances of this application which consume from a topic with 125 partitions. There are 21 consumer threads per consumer instance.

We are seeing a problem with the following command:

`kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $BROKERS --group group_to_describe --describe`

When we bring one instance online and it joins the consumer group, the above command works perfectly. However, we are seeing inconsistent results thereafter. For example, if we bring a further 2 instances online and then issue the above command, we get the following error:

`Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to null`

This is inconsistent in that we could have 3 or 4 consumer instances successfully join the group and the command will work, and other times we can get no more than 2 to join.

The consumer instances still seem to be processing data, however we just can't describe the group and view the lag, partitions assigned, consumers in the group, etc.

Does anybody have any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Having `6*21=126` consumers already consuming a topic with 125 partitions will mean that one consumer thread stays idle. This is my guess: As soon as you add one more consumer instance it causes a rebalance of the consumers. One new consumer seems to be fine, but 2 or more might be a bigger problem causing the consumer group command to fail (or timeout?). Is the command still failing after some time (couple of minutes)?

Comment: Hey @mike, the command still fails after some time unfortunately, yes. So would you say something like 5 instances with 25 consumer threads would be healthier?

Comment: yes, there is (almost) no reason to have more consumer threads than partitions in a topic because one topic partition can be consumed by at most one consumer thread. The only reason to have some consumer threads being idle is so they can keep up with the state and jump in easily if one of the working consumers fail.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the `kafka-consumer-group.sh` tool. Please file a bug report.